Fix issue in GlazeWM for windows (tiling window manager)
I have used i3 wm for a lot of time!
I wanted to have a similar setup in windows 11
I felt GlazeWM is good to go
however,
keybindings:
Shift focus in a given direction.

command: "focus left"
bindings: ["Alt + L", "Alt + Left"]
command: "focus right"
bindings: ["Alt + Semicolon", "Alt + Right"]
command: "focus up"
bindings: ["Alt + K", "Alt + Up"]
command: "focus down"
bindings: ["Alt + J", "Alt + Down"]

Move focused window in a given direction.

command: "move left"
bindings: ["Alt + Shift + Semicolon", "Alt + Shift + Right"]
command: "move right"
bindings: ["Alt + Shift + L", "Alt + Shift + Up"]
command: "move up"
bindings: ["Alt + Shift + K", "Alt + Shift + Down"]
command: "move down"
bindings: ["Alt + Shift + J", "Alt + Shift + Left"]

for Alt + Shift + Semicolon (I tried with semicolon , ; and SEMICOLON) It shows error
How do I fix this ?

Semicolon is defined as OemSemicolon.
Reference: https://github.com/glzr-io/glazewm/issues/97
